# Java - Swing & Slick2D Application, changing windows

Tags: java, swing, slick2d

I'm making simple racing game. I decided to use Swing for menu, lobby, chat etc. and Slick2D library. I have a big problem with moving between Swing and Slick window. But maybe I try to explain how my app should work at first:

1. We have the main menu where we can choose singleplayer or multiplayer. When I click at "singleplayer", visibility of swing window is changed to false value and the constructor of game(Slick part) is called.

   else if (source==bSingle)
   {
       setVisible(false);
       Game game = new Game("Oversteer", 0, okno_menu);
   }
2. Game starts. Everything is fine. When I want back to main menu I need to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Little menu will show (based only on strings) and when I hit <kbd>M</kbd>, I will back to main menu.

   ```
       if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_M))
       {               
           okno_menu2.setVisible(true);
           gc.setForceExit(false);         
           gc.exit();          
       }
   ```

But when I hit singleplayer button in main menu again, slick window appears, but it doesn't have any content (blank, white screen). Window responds for key input, car is moving (coordinates are changing).

I tried to call `gameContainer` function `gc.reinit()`. After that, all sprites are visible, but instead of FPS counter we have bunch of white pixels. Also menu based on strings doesn't show anymore (but it works).

Now I'm really confused. I'll be very glad for any idea or solution for this problem.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't switch between graphics libraries throughout your game, it will make everything terribly complicated later. Use Slick2D for GUIs too, it is not that hard (for simple menus a string with a rectangle as hitbox will do). :)